# When using subprocess passthrough is not accepting both inputs

Tags: php, bash, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

Im trying to have two subprocesses pipe into one and output via the passthrough. My goal is to make it possible to download 2 files (one video and one audio) and combine them with ffmpeg.

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"ok.mp4\"");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");

$cmd = "<(youtube-dl -f bestvideo[ext=mp4] --no-part --no-cache-dir --no-warnings --no-progress -o - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Dh-RL__uN4) <(youtube-dl -f bestaudio[ext=m4a] --no-part --no-cache-dir --no-warnings --no-progress -o - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Dh-RL__uN4) | ffmpeg -i - -i pipe:3 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov+faststart -frag_duration 3600 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mp4 -";

$cmd = passthru($cmd, $status);
```

My error is: -bash: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied

Comment: First put all of this in a bash file and run it directly and see if it works. Then you want to probably run the bash file via passthru and try?

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is the same, always the "permission denied" problem

Comment: I am getting: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: I've read your question several times but I am still confused. You want to download the audio and video separately, then combine with ffmpeg, but you don't want to use `youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/bestvideo+bestaudio' --merge-output-format mp4 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Dh-RL__uN4"` for some reason?

Comment: In this case, the files will be stored on the server and the download by the end user cannot be done at the same time, and this is not the goal.

Comment: So i'm not able to reproduce a dummy version of your program but seems that you are trying to access in a concurrent way the same file identified with the file descriptor 63. If you can provide some simple version of your program, I can check what can I do

Answer (score 3):

when you use

```
 <(command)
```

you execute the command inside the parentheses and the whole thing is replaced by a file descriptor
which is connected to the stdout. /dev/fd/63 is the pipe containing the output of youtube-dl

the `command` is being replaced with a pipe in your case /dev/fd/63 and tries to call /dev/fd/63 as an executable which is not.
its the actual output of the youtube-dl command

so i suggest to either save to 2 files and then pipe them to ffmpep, or use `cat` the downloaded file and pipe it to ffmpeg and then do the same for the second file